# Privileged intents suddenly cause my bot to stop responding

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I'm running a discord bot that contains the following code:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
```

With this code in my program, the bot stops responding to commands. Can anyone please help me out?

In case you're wondering, here is the purpose of the `intents.members = True` line:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(member)
    print(member.guild.id)

    with open('servers.json', 'r') as f:
      serverdict = json.load(f)

    joinTestEmbed = discord.Embed(
        title = "New Member Alert!",
        color = 0x63cf5b,
        description = "A new user has joined this here server! Please welcome" + member.mention + "!"
    ) 
    joinTestEmbed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
    cid = int()
    for server in serverdict:
      if int(server) == member.guild.id:
        print("check")
        cid = serverdict[server] 
    print("cid: ",cid)
    channel = client.get_channel(cid)
    print(channel)
    await channel.send(embed=joinTestEmbed)
    await member.send(f'Hey, {member} welcome to {member.guild.name}! Enjoy your stay!')
```

Comment: have you enabled intents in the discord developer portal?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. :(

Comment: When you created your bot instance, did you pass in intents? Did it look something like `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=intents)`

Comment: I set intents as a variable with its value being discord.Intents.default(). And then I used the line you just commented, so yes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: tried this, didn't work. :(